# How to progressively blur a SKSpriteNode's image using Sprite Kit?

Tags: objective-c, transition, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Can someone provide an example of how to progressively blur a SKSpriteNode's image using Apple's Sprite Kit?  For instance, let's say the user touches a button on the screen which will then trigger the background to slowly (i.e. progressively) blur until it reaches a specific threshold.  Ideally, I would like to reverse the process too (e.g. allow the user to unblur the image by touching the same button).

Comment: Have you looked at SKEffectNode yet ?

Answer (score 7):

There are two possible paths to take on this, both use SKEffectNodes

SKEffectNodes allow you to apply CI Filters to a node.

There is a CI Filter for Gaussian Blur. So Create a SKEffectNode, and assign it a blur filter, then add the button as a child.

How do you animate it?

Use SKAction to create a custom action, and change the parameters of filter, however, this can be slow and doesn't always give the 'progressive' blur effect you might expect, so what I do is this:

I create a filter and SKEffectNode like described above, then I render the result to a Texture, using SKView.textureForNode. I then add the resulting texture to an array, after that I loop this, continuinng to apply the blur effect on top of the previous image created, until I have a set number of frames. Then use the textures created to make an animation with SKAction.animateWithTextures. In my experience, this comes out very nicely.