# SpriteKit: How to blur the movement of a node like a shooting star

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to blur the movement of fast moving nodes. I should look like it fades away behind the movement. Is there some easy solution to archive this?

It should somehow look like this movement:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I tried to call this every 0.0X seconds:

```
 for child in self.allNodes{          
            let node = SKSpriteNode(color: child.color, size: CGSizeMake(size, size))
            node.position = child.position
            self.addChild(node)
            node.runAction(SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.2))
}
```

The problem is, that this solution is to expensive. It should be way easier. :/

Comment: Take a look at this if you are interested in a blur effect : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19734016/3402095 Also, I see you say that particle emitter is expensive for you and not what you are looking for. You say you just need a node to fade away, right ? Then why not just use fadeOut SKAction ?

Comment: I dont need the node to fade away. I need the trail of the node to fade away. (Like a shooting star)

Comment: Ah okay...Well in that case, the easiest and probably most performant solution would be SKEmitterNode (SpriteKit is pretty much optimized for this). But that's just me :) Also maybe you can try with predefined animation (animateWithTextures).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo can create custom `SpriteKit Particle File` with `fire` effect. Then change it `SpriteKit Particle Emmitter` like you want to create effect you need. And create `SKEmitterNode` with with this particle effect like this:

```
// Create path name to file with particle effect
let sparkEmitterPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Spark", ofType: "sks")!

// Create SKEmitterNode from this file
let sparkEmiter = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(sparkEmitterPath) as SKEmitterNode

// Configure it 
sparkEmiter.position = point
sparkEmiter.name = "sparkEmitter"
sparkEmiter.zPosition = 0
sparkEmiter.targetNode = self

// Add to Scene
self.addChild(sparkEmiter)
```

In example file name is `Spark.sks`

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is a little to expensive for my project. The effect doesn't need to sparkle. The node just needs to slowly fade away